# Seeing if anyone can possibly tell me what brick this is

Tags: part-identification

Trying to find out what kind of brick this is for a wedding book that I'm trying to make and will need quite a few of these.

[image: mystery bricks]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is [Brick, Modified 1 x 2 x 1 2/3 with Studs on Side](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=22885) (22885)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

To expand on Alex's answer, an example of it being used can be found in set 60243 - Police Helicopter chase

[image: Instruction showing piece being used on the jewellery truck]

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I edited the Alex answer for later.